# How do i sort the values in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 innings    batsman     batsman_runs
    1          AA Noffke     9
    1          B Akhil       0
    1          BB McCullum  158
    1          CL White      6
    1          DJ Hussey     12....
```

I need to sort the batsman_runs in descending order and also show their corresponding batsman i.e if 158 is at the top, then BB McCullum should be in the adjacent cell. I tried the following code:

```
df['batsman_runs'].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

But this code does not show the batsman name. How do i show the runs with the corresponding batsman ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
In [32]: df.sort_values('batsman_runs', ascending=0)
Out[32]:
   innings      batsman  batsman_runs
2        1  BB McCullum           158
4        1    DJ Hussey            12
0        1    AA Noffke             9
3        1     CL White             6
1        1      B Akhil             0
```

or:

```
In [31]: df.sort_values('batsman', ascending=0)
Out[31]:
   innings      batsman  batsman_runs
4        1    DJ Hussey            12
3        1     CL White             6
2        1  BB McCullum           158
1        1      B Akhil             0
0        1    AA Noffke             9
```

you can also combine several columns:

```
In [34]: df.sort_values(['batsman','batsman_runs'], ascending=[1,0])
Out[34]:
   innings      batsman  batsman_runs
0        1    AA Noffke             9
1        1      B Akhil             0
2        1  BB McCullum           158
3        1     CL White             6
4        1    DJ Hussey            12
```